# How to make nonstopmode really not stop on a missing input file

Tags: errors, input

I have a file `test.tex` with these contents:

```
\input{missing}
\input{present}
```

When I run PDFLaTeX with `--interaction=nonstopmode` it stops after the first missing input file:

```
$ pdflatex --interaction=nonstopmode test
This is pdfTeXk, Version 3.1415926-1.40.9 (Web2C 7.5.7)
 %&-line parsing enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2005/12/01>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, nohyphenation, german-x-2008-06-18, ngerman-x-2008-06-18, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabic, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, galician, german, ngerman, monogreek, greek, hungarian, icelandic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, latin, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolian2a, bokmal, nynorsk, polish, portuguese, romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, welsh, loaded.

! LaTeX Error: File `missing.tex' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: tex)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.1 \input{missing}
                   ^^M
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on test.log.
```

How can I make PDFLaTeX continue even when `missing.tex` is not there? I would like to do this with either command-line options or code I can put at the beginning of any arbitrary source file, not changing the body of the source file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The LaTeX macro

```
\IfFileExists{<filename>}{<true code>}{<false code>}
```

is what you're looking for in the following way:

```
\IfFileExists{missing.tex}{\input{missing}}{}
```

An abbreviated version of the above exists in the form:

```
\InputIfFileExists{<filename>}{<before code>}
```

In short, the above defaults to

```
\IfFileExists{<filename>}{<before code>\input{<filename>}}
```

---

**Edit**: In your comment, you mention that you are interested in appending `.tex` to `missing` if it is not supplied and *only* then. To that end, the [`xstring` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring) provides `\IfEndWith{<string>}{<substr>}{<true code>}{<false code>}` that executes `<true code>` if `<string>` ends with `<substr>`, and `<false code>` otherwise. I used `.tex` for `<substr>` in the following code:

```
\usepackage{xstring}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring
\let\OldInputIfFileExists\InputIfFileExists
\renewcommand{\InputIfFileExists}[2]{%
  \IfFileExists{#1}%
    {\OldInputIfFileExists{#1}{#2}}%
    {\IfEndWith{#1}{.tex}{\typeout{INPUT #1}}{\typeout{INPUT #1.tex}}}%
  }
```

Comment: I didn't specify the problem carefully enough before. Now edited to include: I would like to do this without changing the body of the file, only command-line options or the beginning. But maybe I could get this to work by `\let\oldinput\input \let\input\newinput` where `\newinput` is a command that actually calls `\InputIfFileExists` instead?

Comment: You could also try a recursive `\input`, keeping the source file the same, but modifying the input file, which inputs another file. Would that work? I just tried it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I've been trying something like `\let\OldInputIfFileExists\InputIfFileExists\renewcommand{\InputIfFileExists}[3]{\IfFileExists{#1}{\OldInputIfFileExists{#1}{#2}{#3}}{\typeout{ERROR #1}}}\input{$*}`. Apparently LaTeX `\input` works by calling `\InputIfFileExists` which is an easier place to fix this.

Comment: I would suggest editing your original question and add a separate **Edit** at the bottom. Include what you've done thus far, and what is still not working. Remember that someone is reading this without context, so provide as much of that as possible.

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide a means for conditionally adding `.tex` to a missing filename.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter
\def\input@message{\typeout{\if@tempswa INPUT\else MISSING\fi\space
  \filename@base.\ifx\filename@ext\relax tex\else\filename@ext\fi}}
\renewcommand*\@iinput[1]{%
  \filename@parse{#1}%
  \InputIfFileExists {#1}{\@tempswatrue}{\@tempswafalse}%
  \input@message
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\input{hoffman1}%existent
\input{hoffman2.dat}%existent
\input{hoffman3}%non existent
\end{document}
```

The relevant part of the log file is

```
(./hoffman1.tex)
INPUT hoffman1.tex
(./hoffman2.dat)
INPUT hoffman2.dat
MISSING hoffman3.tex
```

`\@iinput` is the macro called by `\input` when it's followed by an open brace.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, since LaTeX `\input` calls `\InputIfFileExists` under the hood:

```
\let\OldInputIfFileExists\InputIfFileExists
\renewcommand{\InputIfFileExists}[3]{\IfFileExists{#1}{\OldInputIfFileExists{#1}{#2}{#3}}{\typeout{INPUT #1}}}
```

Thanks to Werner for pointing out the existence of these commands.

The only problem I have remaining is that I would like the `\typeout` to add `.tex` to the filename when appropriate, but only then. For example, I would like to change this such that:

```
\input{missing.tex}
\input{missing}
```

will result in the log lines

```
INPUT missing.tex
INPUT missing.tex
```

But I suppose that is another question.

Comment: Rather post this as an edit to your original question, unless you feel that this answers your original question. Also note that `\InputIfFileExists` takes only 2 mandatory arguments, not 3.

Comment: If you look at my answer, you'll see that it adds the required extension with minimal intervention on commands.