# Does \InputIfFileExists not work anymore?

Tags: conditionals

For several years I've used the following in most LaTeX documents to input a macros file that lives in different folders on my Mac and my Linux machine:

```
\InputIfFileExists{/Mac/path/macros.tex}%
{\input{/Mac/path/macros.tex}}
{\input{/linux/path/macros.tex}}
```

It worked splendidly until I recently updated my TeX distribution. After updating, I got an error even with this MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\InputIfFileExists{/Mac/path/macros.tex}%
{\input{/Mac/path/macros.tex}}
{\input{/linux/path/macros.tex}}
\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

The error reads:

```
Command \first already defined. Or name \end... illegal, see p. 192 of the manual.
```

(Here `\first` is the first command defined in my file `macros.tex`.)

I see now that changing to `\IfFileExists` fixes everything, and I'm happy to do that. I'm curious, though, why does `\InputIfFileExists` throw this error?

A quick Something search for `\InputIfFileExists` didn't turn up much useful, just [this old TeX.SE question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33086/how-to-make-nonstopmode-really-not-stop-on-a-missing-input-file).

Comment: As the name implies, if the file is found it is inputted, and then the second arg is executed inputting the file again, thus error

Comment: This presumably never worked, but why not just use `\input{macros}` the test should not be needed, presumably `amsart.cls` is in a different location on the two machines but you do not need to refer to the path at all, just the local file name and arrange the search paths are set up correctly in both cases.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

TL;DR: You're actually looking for

```
\IfFileExists{/Mac/path/macros.tex}%
  {\input{/Mac/path/macros.tex}}
  {\input{/linux/path/macros.tex}}
```

---

The macro `\InputIfFileExists{<file>}{<true>}{<false>}` takes three arguments: the file to check the existence of, the `<true>` code to execute before inputting the file in case it is found and the `<false>` code to execute if the file doesn't exist. The way you're using it makes me think you're actually looking for `\IfFileExists`, which is why it works when you switch to that notation.

In your usage

```
\InputIfFileExists{/Mac/path/macros.tex}%
  {\input{/Mac/path/macros.tex}}
  {\input{/linux/path/macros.tex}}
```

`\InputIfFileExists{<one>}{<two>}{<three>}` checks for the existence of `<one>`. If it exists, it will *necessarily* execute `\input{<one>}`. So, if `/Mac/path/macros.tex` exists, you'll actually end up trying to `\input{/Mac/path/macros.tex}` *twice*.

The code `\input{/linux/path/macros.tex}` will be executed when the file `<one>` doesn't exist.

---

If the only reason for conditioning on the path stems from a choice of your operating system, you might be interested in looking at the [`ifplatform` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/ifplatform). See [Is there a macro telling which OS we're using?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84652/5764).

Comment: NTL;R. +1.   Nice answer.

Comment: All good, except that `\InputIfFileExist` has three arguments (see `clsguide.pdf`, section 4.8): `\InputIfFileExists{⟨file-name⟩}{⟨true⟩}{⟨false⟩}`. It's true that the macro is defined having two, but that's the internal implementation: at the user's level, it should be considered as having three arguments.

Comment: +1. Thanks! This clears it up. I still wonder why it compiled without error under TeX Live 2012, though.

Comment: @ZNorwood it would (does) compile without error on linux as then the test is false so the file is only input once, it would always fail if the tested file is there and contains commands like \newcommand that can not be executed twice.

Answer (score 7):

There has been no change to `\InputIfFileExists` since 1995/05/25 so unless you have not upgraded for a long time the system upgrade is probably unrelated.

However a better, more portable, and more efficient, markup here would be

```
\documentclass{amsart}
  \input{macros}
\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

or better still rename `macros.tex` to `macros.sty` and use

```
\documentclass{amsart}
  \usepackage{macros}
\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

Just as you do not have to give the full path to `amsart.cls` and then customise that path on every machine, you should not have to give the full path to locally produced files.

You just need to ensure that `macros.tex` (or `macros.sty`) is in the TEXINPUTS path, either by adding the location to the standard path or putting the files into a standard place. So on linux texlive `~/texmf/tex/latex/mymacros/macro.sty` would work by default for example (`kpsexpand '$TEXMFHOME'` will show the value of TEXMFHOME but it defaults to `$HOME/texmf`)

Comment: Good suggestion. The reason I use separate paths is just that I like to keep my macros file in my Dropbox, which lives in different places on my different machines. I suppose I could sym-link it to the TeX directory, but, you know, old habits die hard.

Comment: @ZNorwood just put your dropbox directory tree into your TEXINPUTS variable you do not have to move or link anything.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't read that carefully the first time.